# Colours not printing - connect 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pygame, pycharm

Im trying to write a connect 4 game with a GUI, but i cant get the colours to print where i click, ive got it print the colours where the space = 0, ive also got it to work where when i click the 1 and 2s are printed onto the text version of the board, however on the graphical one im trying to get the colours to print in correspondence to the number of the player inputted.
Any help appreciated thanks.

```
import numpy as np
import pygame
import sys
import math

BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
ROW_COUNT = 6
COLUMN_COUNT = 7

def create_board(): # board creation
    board = np.zeros((ROW_COUNT,COLUMN_COUNT))
    return board
def drop_piece(board,row,column, piece): #the dropping of player counters
    board[row][column] = piece

def is_valid_location(board, column): # checks if the location entered is valid to be used
    return board[ROW_COUNT - 1][column] == 0 # if not true column is full

def get_next_open_row(board,column): # checks which row the piece will fall on
    for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
        if board[r][column] == 0:
            return r
def print_board(board): # flips the board so numbers stack from bottom to top
    print(np.flip(board, 0))

def winning_move(board, piece):

    # check horizontal locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT-3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r][c+1] == piece and board[r][c+2] == piece and board[r][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    # check for vertical locations for win
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT - 3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c] == piece and board[r+2][c] == piece and board[r+3][c] == piece:
                return True

    #check for positively sloped diagonals
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT - 3):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT - 3):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r+1][c+1] == piece and board[r+2][c+2] == piece and board[r+3][c+3] == piece:
                return True

    #check for negatively sloped diagonals
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT - 3):
        for r in range(3,ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == piece and board[r-1][c+1] == piece and board[r-2][c+2] == piece and board[r-3][c+3] == piece:
                return True

def draw_board(board):
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (c*SQUARESIZE, r*SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE, SQUARESIZE, SQUARESIZE))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (int(c*SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE/2), int(r*SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE+SQUARESIZE/2)), RADIUS)

    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):

            if board[r][c] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (int(c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2), HEIGHT - int(r * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2)), RADIUS)
            elif board[r][c] == 2:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW,(int(c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2), HEIGHT - int(r * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE / 2)),RADIUS)
    pygame.display.update()


board = create_board()
print_board(board)
game_over = False
turn = 0

# https://www.pygame.org/docs/    <----- pygame commands
pygame.init()
SQUARESIZE = 100

WIDTH = COLUMN_COUNT * SQUARESIZE

HEIGHT = (ROW_COUNT+1) * SQUARESIZE

size = (WIDTH,HEIGHT)

RADIUS = int(SQUARESIZE/2 - 5 )

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
draw_board(board)
pygame.display.update()

while not game_over:
#asks for player 1 input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
           # print(event.pos)



            try:
                
        
                if turn == 0:
                    posx = event.pos[0]
                    column = int(math.floor(posx/SQUARESIZE))
                    print(column)
        
                    if is_valid_location(board, column):
                        row = get_next_open_row(board, column)
                        drop_piece(board, row, column, 1)
        
                        if winning_move(board,1):
                            print("PLAYER 1 WINS")
                            game_over = True


        #asks for player 2 input
                else:
                    posx = event.pos[0]
                    column = int(math.floor(posx / SQUARESIZE))
                    print(column)
        
                    if is_valid_location(board, column):
                        row = get_next_open_row(board, column)
                        drop_piece(board, row, column, 2)
        
                    if winning_move(board, 2):
                        print("PLAYER 2 WINS")
                        game_over = True
                        break
        
                print_board(board)
                turn = turn + 1
                turn = turn % 2 #alternates between the two players
            except:
        
                if turn == 0:
                    column = int(input("Player 1 Make your selection (0-6):"))
                    print(column)
        
                    if is_valid_location(board, column):
                        row = get_next_open_row(board, column)
                        drop_piece(board, row, column, 1)
        
                        if winning_move(board,1):
        
                            print("PLAYER 1 WINS")
                            game_over = True
        
                # asks for player 2 input
                else:
                    column = int(input("Player 2 Make your selection (0-6):"))
                    print(column)
        
                    if is_valid_location(board, column):
                        row = get_next_open_row(board, column)
                        drop_piece(board, row, column, 2)
        
                    if winning_move(board, 2):
                        print("PLAYER 2 WINS")
                        game_over = True
                        break
        
                print_board(board)
                draw_board(board)
                turn = turn + 1
                turn = turn % 2  # alternates between the two players
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top of a cell is `HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE` and the center of a cell is `HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE // 2`:

```py
def draw_board(board):
    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, BLUE, (c * SQUARESIZE, HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE, SQUARESIZE, SQUARESIZE))
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLACK, (c* SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE // 2, HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE // 2), RADIUS)

    for c in range(COLUMN_COUNT):
        for r in range(ROW_COUNT):
            if board[r][c] == 1:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, GREEN, (c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE // 2, HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE // 2), RADIUS)
            elif board[r][c] == 2:
                pygame.draw.circle(screen, YELLOW,(c * SQUARESIZE + SQUARESIZE // 2, HEIGHT - r * SQUARESIZE - SQUARESIZE // 2),RADIUS)
```

I recommend to draw the grid continuously in the application loop:

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while not game_over:
    clock.tick(60)
    screen.fill(0)
    draw_board(board)
    pygame.display.update()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        # [...]
```

[image]

---

The typical PyGame application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)
- limit frames per second to limit CPU usage

Use [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) to control the frames per second and thus the game speed.

The method [`tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) of a [`pygame.time.Clock`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) object, delays the game in that way, that every iteration of the loop consumes the same period of time. See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame.

That means that the loop:

> ```py
> clock = pygame.time.Clock()
> run = True
> while run:
>    clock.tick(60)
> ```

runs 60 times per second.

See [`pygame.time.Clock.tick()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick):

> This method should be called once per frame. It will compute how many milliseconds have passed since the previous call.